# How to generate privatePEMKey & thumbprint for passport-azure-ad

Tags: javascript, node.js, openid-connect, passport-azure-ad

I have a base64 certificate file which looks something like this (with a valid, correctly formatted upper-case base64).

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I'm trying to create code in nodejs to generate the `privatePEMKey` & `thumbprint` for my config.

```
var config = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('./config.json'));
var cert = require('x509').parseCert('./mycert.cert');

//For thumbprint and privatePEMKey parameters, you need to specify a certificate for your app and register the public key in Azure Active Directory.
//- thumbprint is the base64url format of the thumbprint of the public key
//- privatePEMKey is the private pem key string.
config.creds.thumbprint = cert.fingerPrint.replace(/:/g,'').toString('base64');
config.creds.privatePEMKey = cert.publicKey.n;
```

If I run this I still get the error:

> Error: privatePEMKey is not provided. Please provide either
>   clientSecret, or privatePEMKey and thumbprint.

My question is what am I missing ?
- does it make any difference if the 'strings' are in upper/lower case ?

Documentation via:
https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad#622-fill-the-test-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Typically a certificate file is a public key and I suspect the privatePEMKey line above is the problem.

I use some [scripts](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/tree/master/api/certs) that produce TLS 1.2 public / private certs for local PC development:

- mycompany.ssl.crt = public key
- mycompany.ssl.key = private key

Maybe try running your code against my public + private key files and see if you get a little further. If so then adapting my makeCerts script may resolve your problem.